# Mount a Rack App Explicitly Inside a Sinatra::App

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to mount another Rack app from within my Sinatra app.

So instead of this:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new('/' => MyApp, `/other` => OtherApp)
```

I want to...

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  # ...mount the other rack app in here.
end
```

Yes, I understand this might not be the beaten path... but that's precisely why I'm asking. Trust me, I have good reasons.

Comment: Adding your use case might help.

Comment: Can you explain what is that you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to mount your app as middle-ware or to pass the request on to your app from a specific path in Sinatra?

Comment: When the user visits /whatever, that request is routed to the app. The issue is I need this to be loaded from within the Sinatra apps namespace.